# GUI: How to translate the coordinate

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there, I'm learning how to use the GUI of gazebo sim. I can rotate or scale an object in the simulator by dragging with left or right button, but I can't translate the coordinate. Do anyone know how to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2821/gui:-how-to-translate-the-coordinate/) by [Yoshimaru Tanaka](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/347/yoshimaru-tanaka/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started_gui.html

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0